# Unexpected directive value error with Angular2 GWT integration

Tags: javascript, gwt, angular

I am trying to use Angular2(only JavaScript, no TypeScript) with in GWT 2.6.0

Have a very basic code like this:

```
public native void init() /*-{
  var MyComp= $wnd.ng.Component({
  selector: 'my-sample',
  properties:['model']
  })
  .View({
  directives: [], 
  template: '\n<h1>Hello world!</h1>'
  })
  .Class({
    constructor: function() {
    }
  });
  var MyApp= $wnd.ng.Component({selector:'my-app'})
  .View({
    directives: [MyComp],
    template:'<my-sample></my-sample>'
  })
  .Class({
    constructor:function(){}
  });
  $wnd.setTimeout(function() { $wnd.ng.bootstrap(MyApp);}, 1000);
}-*/;
```

But the <my-sample></my-sample> in my template results in this error:

```
angular2.sfx.dev.js:33004 EXCEPTION: Unexpected directive value 'function (){' on the View of component 'function (){'System.register.BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ angular2.sfx.dev.js:33004System.register.BrowserDomAdapter.logGroup @ angular2.sfx.dev.js:33015System.register.ExceptionHandler.call @ angular2.sfx.dev.js:4792(anonymous function) @ angular2.sfx.dev.js:28798System.register.NgZone._onError @ angular2.sfx.dev.js:11072System.register.NgZone._createInnerZone.errorHandling.onError @ angular2.sfx.dev.js:10991run @ angular2.sfx.dev.js:141System.register.NgZone._createInnerZone.zone.fork.fork.$run @ angular2.sfx.dev.js:11005zoneBoundFn @ angular2.sfx.dev.js:111lib$es6$promise$$internal$$tryCatch @ angular2.sfx.dev.js:1507lib$es6$promise$$internal$$invokeCallback @ angular2.sfx.dev.js:1519lib$es6$promise$$internal$$publish @ angular2.sfx.dev.js:1490(anonymous function) @ angular2.sfx.dev.js:219System.register.NgZone._createInnerZone.zone.fork.fork.$scheduleMicrotask.microtask @ angular2.sfx.dev.js:11031run @ angular2.sfx.dev.js:138System.register.NgZone._createInnerZone.zone.fork.fork.$run @ angular2.sfx.dev.js:11005zoneBoundFn @ angular2.sfx.dev.js:111lib$es6$promise$asap$$flush @ angular2.sfx.dev.js:1301
angular2.sfx.dev.js:33004 STACKTRACE:System.register.BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ angular2.sfx.dev.js:33004System.register.ExceptionHandler.call @ angular2.sfx.dev.js:4794(anonymous function) @ angular2.sfx.dev.js:28798System.register.NgZone._onError @ angular2.sfx.dev.js:11072System.register.NgZone._createInnerZone.errorHandling.onError @ angular2.sfx.dev.js:10991run @ angular2.sfx.dev.js:141System.register.NgZone._createInnerZone.zone.fork.fork.$run @ angular2.sfx.dev.js:11005zoneBoundFn @ angular2.sfx.dev.js:111lib$es6$promise$$internal$$tryCatch @ angular2.sfx.dev.js:1507lib$es6$promise$$internal$$invokeCallback @ angular2.sfx.dev.js:1519lib$es6$promise$$internal$$publish @ angular2.sfx.dev.js:1490(anonymous function) @ angular2.sfx.dev.js:219System.register.NgZone._createInnerZone.zone.fork.fork.$scheduleMicrotask.microtask @ angular2.sfx.dev.js:11031run @ angular2.sfx.dev.js:138System.register.NgZone._createInnerZone.zone.fork.fork.$run @ angular2.sfx.dev.js:11005zoneBoundFn @ angular2.sfx.dev.js:111lib$es6$promise$asap$$flush @ angular2.sfx.dev.js:1301
angular2.sfx.dev.js:33004 Error: Unexpected directive value 'function (){' on the View of component 'function (){'
    at new BaseException (http://127.0.0.1:8888/angular2demo/angular2.sfx.dev.js:25289:21)
    at RuntimeMetadataResolver.System.register.RuntimeMetadataResolver.getViewDirectivesMetadata (http://127.0.0.1:8888/angular2demo/angular2.sfx.dev.js:13091:17)
    at RuntimeCommandFactory.componentTemplateFactory (http://127.0.0.1:8888/angular2demo/angular2.sfx.dev.js:36943:66)
    at RuntimeCommandFactory.System.register.RuntimeCommandFactory.createBeginComponent (http://127.0.0.1:8888/angular2demo/angular2.sfx.dev.js:12451:33)
    at CommandBuilderVisitor.System.register.CommandBuilderVisitor.visitElement (http://127.0.0.1:8888/angular2demo/angular2.sfx.dev.js:12572:46)
    at ElementAst.System.register.ElementAst.visit (http://127.0.0.1:8888/angular2demo/angular2.sfx.dev.js:11797:22)
    at http://127.0.0.1:8888/angular2demo/angular2.sfx.dev.js:11876:27
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.templateVisitAll (http://127.0.0.1:8888/angular2demo/angular2.sfx.dev.js:11875:10)
    at CommandCompiler.System.register.CommandCompiler.compileComponentRuntime (http://127.0.0.1:8888/angular2demo/angular2.sfx.dev.js:12400:22)
```

I just pulled out the native code and pasted in an non-GWT application HTML file script tag(by just replacing $wnd with window) and everything just works fine.

What this error is and how can I fix it?

**2016/03/22:**
After Eric's response, I tried with the UMD bundle and now generating a code like this in GWT.

```
public native void init() /*-{
    if (!$wnd.SampleApp)
        $wnd.SampleApp = {}
    $wnd.SampleApp.SampleComponent =
      $wnd.ng.core.Component({
          selector: 'my-sample',
    template: '\n<h1>Hello world!</h1>'
          })
          .Class({
            constructor: function() {}
          });
    $wnd.SampleApp.Main =
    $wnd.ng.core.Component({
        selector: 'my-app',
        directives: [$wnd.SampleApp.SampleComponent],
        template: '<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>'
    })
    .Class({
    constructor: function() {}
    });
    setTimeout(function() {
        $wnd.ng.platform.browser.bootstrap($wnd.SampleApp.Main);
    }, 3000);
}-*/;
```

But still it gives error:

```
EXCEPTION: Unexpected directive value 'class0' on the View of component 'class1'
browser_adapter.ts:73 EXCEPTION: Unexpected directive value 'class0' on the View of component 'class1'BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ browser_adapter.ts:73BrowserDomAdapter.logGroup @ browser_adapter.ts:84ExceptionHandler.call @ exception_handler.ts:49(anonymous function) @ application_ref.ts:262NgZone._notifyOnError @ ng_zone.ts:453collection_1.StringMapWrapper.merge.onError @ ng_zone.ts:352Zone.run @ angular2-polyfills.js:1247(anonymous function) @ ng_zone.ts:370zoneBoundFn @ angular2-polyfills.js:1220lib$es6$promise$$internal$$tryCatch @ angular2-polyfills.js:468lib$es6$promise$$internal$$invokeCallback @ angular2-polyfills.js:480lib$es6$promise$$internal$$publish @ angular2-polyfills.js:451(anonymous function) @ angular2-polyfills.js:123microtask @ ng_zone.ts:409Zone.run @ angular2-polyfills.js:1243(anonymous function) @ ng_zone.ts:370zoneBoundFn @ angular2-polyfills.js:1220lib$es6$promise$asap$$flush @ angular2-polyfills.js:262
browser_adapter.ts:73 STACKTRACE:BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ browser_adapter.ts:73ExceptionHandler.call @ exception_handler.ts:52(anonymous function) @ application_ref.ts:262NgZone._notifyOnError @ ng_zone.ts:453collection_1.StringMapWrapper.merge.onError @ ng_zone.ts:352Zone.run @ angular2-polyfills.js:1247(anonymous function) @ ng_zone.ts:370zoneBoundFn @ angular2-polyfills.js:1220lib$es6$promise$$internal$$tryCatch @ angular2-polyfills.js:468lib$es6$promise$$internal$$invokeCallback @ angular2-polyfills.js:480lib$es6$promise$$internal$$publish @ angular2-polyfills.js:451(anonymous function) @ angular2-polyfills.js:123microtask @ ng_zone.ts:409Zone.run @ angular2-polyfills.js:1243(anonymous function) @ ng_zone.ts:370zoneBoundFn @ angular2-polyfills.js:1220lib$es6$promise$asap$$flush @ angular2-polyfills.js:262
browser_adapter.ts:73 Error: Unexpected directive value 'class0' on the View of component 'class1'
    at new BaseException (http://127.0.0.1:8888/angular2demo/angular2-all.umd.dev.js:4377:24)
    at RuntimeMetadataResolver.getViewDirectivesMetadata (http://127.0.0.1:8888/angular2demo/angular2-all.umd.dev.js:26882:24)
    at TemplateCompiler._compileNestedComponentRuntime (http://127.0.0.1:8888/angular2demo/angular2-all.umd.dev.js:21535:66)
    at http://127.0.0.1:8888/angular2demo/angular2-all.umd.dev.js:21520:88
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Array.forEach (http://127.0.0.1:8888/angular2demo/es6-shim.min.js:10:16878)
    at http://127.0.0.1:8888/angular2demo/angular2-all.umd.dev.js:21520:44
    at Zone.run (http://127.0.0.1:8888/angular2demo/angular2-polyfills.js:1243:24)
    at Zone.run (http://127.0.0.1:8888/angular2demo/angular2-all.umd.dev.js:13235:43)
    at zoneBoundFn (http://127.0.0.1:8888/angular2demo/angular2-polyfills.js:1220:26)

-----async gap-----
Error
    at _getStacktraceWithUncaughtError (http://127.0.0.1:8888/angular2demo/angular2-polyfills.js:2236:29)
    at Zone.fork (http://127.0.0.1:8888/angular2demo/angular2-polyfills.js:2285:47)
    at Zone.bind (http://127.0.0.1:8888/angular2demo/angular2-polyfills.js:1218:53)
    at bindArguments (http://127.0.0.1:8888/angular2demo/angular2-polyfills.js:1401:36)
    at lib$es6$promise$promise$$Promise.obj.(anonymous function) [as then] (http://127.0.0.1:8888/angular2demo/angular2-polyfills.js:1413:46)
    at TemplateCompiler._compileComponentRuntime (http://127.0.0.1:8888/angular2demo/angular2-all.umd.dev.js:21514:19)
    at TemplateCompiler.compileHostComponentRuntime (http://127.0.0.1:8888/angular2demo/angular2-all.umd.dev.js:21465:19)
    at RuntimeCompiler_.compileInHost (http://127.0.0.1:8888/angular2demo/angular2-all.umd.dev.js:21366:40)
    at DynamicComponentLoader_.loadAsRoot (http://127.0.0.1:8888/angular2demo/angular2-all.umd.dev.js:13658:32)
    at di_1.provide.useFactory (http://127.0.0.1:8888/angular2demo/angular2-all.umd.dev.js:12500:48)

-----async gap-----
Error
    at _getStacktraceWithUncaughtError (http://127.0.0.1:8888/angular2demo/angular2-polyfills.js:2236:29)
    at Zone.fork (http://127.0.0.1:8888/angular2demo/angular2-polyfills.js:2285:47)
    at NgZone._createInnerZone (http://127.0.0.1:8888/angular2demo/angular2-all.umd.dev.js:13223:15)
    at new NgZone (http://127.0.0.1:8888/angular2demo/angular2-all.umd.dev.js:13009:37)
    at createNgZone (http://127.0.0.1:8888/angular2demo/angular2-all.umd.dev.js:12523:13)
    at PlatformRef_.application (http://127.0.0.1:8888/angular2demo/angular2-all.umd.dev.js:12624:34)
    at Object.bootstrap (http://127.0.0.1:8888/angular2demo/angular2-all.umd.dev.js:27196:65)
    at angular2demo-0.js:123:30BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ browser_adapter.ts:73ExceptionHandler.call @ exception_handler.ts:53(anonymous function) @ application_ref.ts:262NgZone._notifyOnError @ ng_zone.ts:453collection_1.StringMapWrapper.merge.onError @ ng_zone.ts:352Zone.run @ angular2-polyfills.js:1247(anonymous function) @ ng_zone.ts:370zoneBoundFn @ angular2-polyfills.js:1220lib$es6$promise$$internal$$tryCatch @ angular2-polyfills.js:468lib$es6$promise$$internal$$invokeCallback @ angular2-polyfills.js:480lib$es6$promise$$internal$$publish @ angular2-polyfills.js:451(anonymous function) @ angular2-polyfills.js:123microtask @ ng_zone.ts:409Zone.run @ angular2-polyfills.js:1243(anonymous function) @ ng_zone.ts:370zoneBoundFn @ angular2-polyfills.js:1220lib$es6$promise$asap$$flush @ angular2-polyfills.js:262
```

Again if I take this code out and put it in a script block of an HTML file, it works. So something wrong happening when running with in GWT.
The GWT code involves compilation steps so I am afraid I can't create a plnkr for it.

Comment: please upgrade your SFX bundle to the new UMD bundle. Sfx bundles were replaced by umd bundles looooong time ago. And if possible provide a plnkr (is that possible when using GWT, know nothing about it)

Comment: Thanks Eric for the response. I just updated my query after running it with the UMD bundle

Comment: can you change these lines `constructor: function() {}` to match the class name? For example, for `$wnd.SampleApp.SampleComponent` you can put `constructor: SampleComponent() {}`. Do this in all your classes, the error should say in which class is failing.

Comment: Here is the error message after the change:
browser_adapter.ts:73 EXCEPTION: Unexpected directive value 'SampleComponent' on the View of component 'Main'

Comment: I guess I can't be more helpful, you already have the error message, and like you said GWT requires some compilation steps. Is there a chance of seeing how the code looks after being compiled by GWT? The code, from ng2 point of view looks perfect. Maybe you can open an issue in GWT repo (do they have one? If that's so you could edit your question and add the link). Honestly I think ng2 is not involved anymore in here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it in a rather unconvincing manner. For the constructor functions, I had to call an external JavaScript file to get a function rather than just defining them in JSNI.

Statements like:

```
  constructor: function() {}
```

above causes this type of error due to some incompatibilities.

I replaced it with something like:

```
  constructor: $wnd.wrapFunction4GWT(function() {})
```

where the wrapper function will return a new function that inherits the one defined in the GWT native layer(as the function will not be empty like this in realtime).

Answer (score 0):

I hope GWT 2.6.0 is not a requirement in your case. If you could switch to GWT 2.8.0 (what also enables Java 8 support), there is another solution. 
Did you try to use angular2-gwt (http://lteconsulting.fr/angular2boot/)? 
Here is a sample Angular2Boot application: https://github.com/ltearno/angular2-gwt. I guess you could use this library also without the Spring backend.

PS: The current GWT approach suggests to use JsInterop over JNI.

Comment: Sorry missed to read your comment.
Thank you very much for this useful info. For the time being we are living with Angular 1.5 integration with GWT 2.6. Angular2Boot looks very promising. We will explore this and upgrade.

Comment: @Denero Thank you for your response. Please do not forget to rate up my answer if this approach seems to be of interest to you :) This will help me to build reputation. Thank you.

Comment: Yes definitely I want to and I tried to do that yesterday. But then got a message that I don't have enough reputation myself to do that operation and it is noting down my request. Hopefully someone will review that and give you the deserved point.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, they have so strict rules.